# Generating thumbnails from videos created using AVAssetWriter

Tags: iphone, ios, video, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I'm recording video+audio using `AVAssetWriter` and the `captureOutput` callback. The problem is that in about 5% of the cases I cannot generate a thumbnail from second zero(If I try to go further in the video, then there is no problem). The error I'm getting is:

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11832 "Cannot Open"
>   UserInfo=0x4b31b0 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=This media cannot be
>   used., NSUnderlyingError=0x4effb0 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (OSStatus error -12431.)", NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot
>   Open}

Here is the code I'm using:

```
AVURLAsset *asset=[[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform=TRUE;
[asset release];
CMTime thumbTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,30);

AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler handler = ^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef im, CMTime actualTime, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error)
{
    if (result != AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded)
    {
        [self NSLogPrint:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"couldn't generate thumbnail, error:%@", error]];
    }

    UIImage *thumbImg=[[UIImage imageWithCGImage:im] retain];   

    [image setImage:thumbImg];
    [thumbImg release];

    [generator release];
};

CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(177, 100);
generator.maximumSize = maxSize;
[generator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:thumbTime]] completionHandler:handler];
```

Here is how I'm setting up my video **AVAssetWriterInput**:

```
- (BOOL) setupAssetWriterVideoInput:(CMFormatDescriptionRef)currentFormatDescription 
{
    float bitsPerPixel;
    CMVideoDimensions dimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(currentFormatDescription);
    int numPixels = dimensions.width * dimensions.height;
    int bitsPerSecond;

    // Assume that lower-than-SD resolutions are intended for streaming, and use a lower bitrate
    if ( numPixels < (640 * 480) )
        bitsPerPixel = 4.05; // This bitrate matches the quality produced by AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium or Low.
    else
        bitsPerPixel = 11.04; // This bitrate matches the quality produced by AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh.

    bitsPerSecond = numPixels * bitsPerPixel;

    NSDictionary *videoCompressionSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                              AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                              [NSNumber numberWithInteger:dimensions.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                                              [NSNumber numberWithInteger:dimensions.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                                              [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                               [NSNumber numberWithInteger:bitsPerSecond], AVVideoAverageBitRateKey,
                                               [NSNumber numberWithInteger:30], AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey,
                                               nil], AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey,
                                              nil];
    if ([_videoWriter canApplyOutputSettings:videoCompressionSettings forMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) 
    {
        self._videoWriterInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput alloc] initWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoCompressionSettings];
        self._videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
        self._videoWriterInput.transform = [self returnOrientation];
        if ([_videoWriter canAddInput:self._videoWriterInput])
            [_videoWriter addInput:self._videoWriterInput];
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Couldn't add asset writer video input.");
            return NO;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't apply video output settings.");
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

I know that the error means there is no image at that time, but why is this happening?

I've also tested recording using AVCaptureMovieFileOutput and the thumbnails are always generated.
Also if I export the video that to camera roll, the preview also isn't available in Photos.

P.S: I've also read somewhere that this may have something to do with the key frame interval, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort of fixed my problem. I was running on iOS 4.2.1,and decided to upgrade to iOS 5.1.1 and the issue dissappeared.

Comment: Occasionally I see this on iOS 8.3

Comment: I see this consistently in iOS 10.3

Comment: 10.3.3 also problem